# Error - Using R shiny app to produce a timeseries and three widgets in the side panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am pretty new to Rshiny and need help (please don't be too brutal, I am trying).
I want to build a shiny app displaying a time series showing number of users from a specific country over a certain period. So a sidebar panel with 3 widgets:

1. "Country" - factor list of 3 countries
2. "User" - factor list of three types of users. Select box where they are able to choose between one or all three user types
3. "Date" calendar allowing you to pick a date between 2020-06-01 - 2021-11-01

Then this will produce one output which is a ggplot line time series showing users from the chosen country.
With the provided code I've only been able show the 3 widgets but the plot itself results the error:

```
Error in output$lineplot <- renderPlot({ : object 'output' not found
```

df

```
Country         date        Users              Count
Angola          2020-06-01  New_users          4
Angola          2020-06-01  Returning_Users    0
Angola          2020-06-01  Active_Users       4
Angola          2020-08-01  New_users          5
Angola          2020-08-01  Returning_Users    2
Angola          2020-08-01  Active_Users       7
Angola          2020-10-01  New_users          1
Angola          2020-10-01  Returning_Users    0
Angola          2020-10-01  Active_Users       1
Angola          2020-11-01  New_users          2
Angola          2020-11-01  Returning_Users    5
Angola          2020-11-01  Active_Users       7
Angola          2020-12-01  New_users          0
Angola          2020-12-01  Returning_Users    6
Angola          2020-12-01  Active_Users       6
Angola          2021-01-01  New_users          6
Angola          2021-01-01  Returning_Users    7
Angola          2021-01-01  Active_Users       13
Angola          2021-02-01  New_users          4
Angola          2021-02-01  Returning_Users    4
Angola          2021-02-01  Active_Users       8
Angola          2021-03-01  New_users          5
Angola          2021-03-01  Returning_Users    3
Angola          2021-03-01  Active_Users       8
Angola          2021-06-01  New_users          1
Angola          2021-06-01  Returning_Users    0
Angola          2021-06-01  Active_Users       1
Angola          2021-07-01  New_users          1
Angola          2021-07-01  Returning_Users    2
Angola          2021-07-01  Active_Users       3
Angola          2021-10-01  New_users          15
Angola          2021-10-01  Returning_Users    14
Angola          2021-10-01  Active_Users       29
Angola          2021-11-01  New_users          44
Angola          2021-11-01  Returning_Users    37
Angola          2021-11-01  Active_Users       81
Kenya           2020-06-01  New_users          32
Kenya           2020-06-01  Returning_Users    0
Kenya           2020-06-01  Active_Users       32
Kenya           2020-08-01  New_users          26
Kenya           2020-08-01  Returning_Users    25
Kenya           2020-08-01  Active_Users       51
Kenya           2020-10-01  New_users          14
Kenya           2020-10-01  Returning_Users    20
Kenya           2020-10-01  Active_Users       34
Kenya           2020-11-01  New_users          9
Kenya           2020-11-01  Returning_Users    17
Kenya           2020-11-01  Active_Users       26
Kenya           2020-12-01  New_users          0
Kenya           2020-12-01  Returning_Users    11
Kenya           2020-12-01  Active_Users       11
Kenya           2021-01-01  New_users          17
Kenya           2021-01-01  Returning_Users    42
Kenya           2021-01-01  Active_Users       59
Kenya           2021-02-01  New_users          28
Kenya           2021-02-01  Returning_Users    37
Kenya           2021-02-01  Active_Users       65
Kenya           2021-03-01  New_users          27
Kenya           2021-03-01  Returning_Users    20
Kenya           2021-03-01  Active_Users       47
Kenya           2021-06-01  New_users          162
Kenya           2021-06-01  Returning_Users    41
Kenya           2021-06-01  Active_Users       203
Kenya           2021-07-01  New_users          187
Kenya           2021-07-01  Returning_Users    68
Kenya           2021-07-01  Active_Users       255
Kenya           2021-10-01  New_users          155
Kenya           2021-10-01  Returning_Users    64
Kenya           2021-10-01  Active_Users       219
Kenya           2021-11-01  New_users          33
Kenya           2021-11-01  Returning_Users    49
Kenya           2021-11-01  Active_Users       82
South Africa    2020-05-01  New_users          19
South Africa    2020-05-01  Returning_Users    0
South Africa    2020-05-01  Active_Users       19
South Africa    2020-06-01  New_users          40
South Africa    2020-06-01  Returning_Users    9
South Africa    2020-06-01  Active_Users       49
South Africa    2020-07-01  New_users          41
South Africa    2020-07-01  Returning_Users    13
South Africa    2020-07-01  Active_Users       54
South Africa    2020-08-01  New_users          64
South Africa    2020-08-01  Returning_Users    20
South Africa    2020-08-01  Active_Users       84
South Africa    2020-10-01  New_users          58
South Africa    2020-10-01  Returning_Users    13
South Africa    2020-10-01  Active_Users       71
South Africa    2020-12-01  New_users          105
South Africa    2020-12-01  Returning_Users    36
South Africa    2020-12-01  Active_Users       141
South Africa    2021-01-01  New_users          47
South Africa    2021-01-01  Returning_Users    37
South Africa    2021-01-01  Active_Users       84
South Africa    2021-02-01  New_users          213
South Africa    2021-02-01  Returning_Users    54
South Africa    2021-02-01  Active_Users       267
South Africa    2021-03-01  New_users          224
South Africa    2021-03-01  Returning_Users    66
South Africa    2021-03-01  Active_Users       290
South Africa    2021-06-01  New_users         122
South Africa    2021-06-01  Returning_Users   94
South Africa    2021-06-01  Active_Users      216
South Africa    2021-07-01  New_users         1428
South Africa    2021-07-01  Returning_Users   78
South Africa    2021-07-01  Active_Users      1506
South Africa    2021-10-01  New_users         457
South Africa    2021-10-01  Returning_Users   433
South Africa    2021-10-01  Active_Users      890
South Africa    2021-11-01  New_users         96
South Africa    2021-11-01  Returning_Users   200
South Africa    2021-11-01  Active_Users      296
```

Code

```
# Load packages -----------------------------------------------------
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# Define UI ---------------------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Users"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    # Select type of trend to plot
                    selectInput(inputId = "type", label = strong("Trend index"),
                                choices = unique(df$Country),
                                selected = "Angola"),
                    
                    checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "selected_user_type",
                                       label = "Select user type",
                                       choices =c ("Active_Users","New_users","Returning_User"),
                                       selected = "New_users"),
                    
                    # Select date range to be plotted
                    dateRangeInput("date", strong("Date range"), 
                                   start = "2020-06-01", end = "2021-11-01",
                                   min = "2020-06-01", max = "2021-11-01"),
                  ),
                  # Output: Description, lineplot, and reference
                  mainPanel(
                    plotOutput(outputId = "lineplot", height = "300px"),
                    textOutput(outputId = "desc"),
                    tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/finance/domestic_trends", "Source: Google Domestic Trends", target = "_blank")
                  )
                )
)

# Define server function --------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Subset data
  
  users_subset <- reactive({ 
    req(input$selected_user_type) 
    filter(df, Users %in% input$selected_user_type)
  }) 
  
  
  selected_trends <- reactive({
    req(input$date)
    validate(need(!is.na(input$date[1]) & !is.na(input$date[2]), "Error: Please provide both a start and an end date."))
    validate(need(input$date[1] < input$date[2], "Error: Start date should be earlier than end date."))
    df%>%
      filter(
        users_subset,
        date > as.POSIXct(input$date[1]) & date < as.POSIXct(input$date[2]
        ))
  })
  
  # Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
}

output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data = selected_trends, aes_string(x = selected_trends()$date, selected_trends()$Count)) +
    geom_line(alpha = input$alpha) +
    labs(x = "Time (Month)", y = "Users")
})

# Create the Shiny app object ---------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't worry. Not everyone is brutal here and Shiny can pose difficulties even for seasoned users given the complex real life data and use cases. Can you at least show the error appearing in console? if its related to ggplot specifically then a search with relevant error may help you without even changing shiny components.  I cannot test it today but with error inputs someone can help.

Comment: Thank you for responding so kindly. I updated the question with a screenshot of the output and the error as well. I really hope this helps a little.

Comment: I think your problem comes from a simple typo: your `output$lineplot` is located outside of the `server` function, therefore it's not recognized as valid R code. You should just put it above the closing `}`.

Comment: That solved something but now I get this error  ```Warning: Error in ggplot:   You're passing a function as global data. Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()` ```

Comment: `selected_trends` is a `reactive()` expression so you need to use `selected_trends()` when you call it, for example `ggplot(selected_trends())`

Comment: More errors: ```Warning: Error in filter: Problem while computing `..1 = users_subset`.
Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Input must be a vector, not a <reactiveExpr/reactive/function> object.
  205: <Anonymous>```

Comment: Same thing, `users_subset` is a reactive so you need to use `users_subset()`

Comment: For some reason it still gives errors :(